# Is there a good way of saving a Spacy doc in a Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, nlp, spacy

I'm in the process of figuring this out but wanted to document on stack overflow since this wasn't easily searchable. (Also, hopefully someone can answer this before I do).

```
df.loc[:,'corpus_spacy_doc'] = df['text_corpus'].apply(lambda cell: nlp(cell))
```

So now I can do all sorts of nlp stuff to *corpus_spacy_doc* which is great. But I would like to have a good way of saving the state of this dataframe since *df.to_csv()* obviously won't work. Been looking to see if this is possible with parquet but I don't think it is.

As of right now it seems my best solution is using the spacy method of serializing the list of docs (https://spacy.io/usage/saving-loading) and loading with pandas dataframe later.

To summarize, I now want a pythonic way of doing something like

```
df.to_something(fname = fname)
```

Has anyone else gone through this or have a good answer?

---

Answer (score 1):

So this was pretty easy and seems to solved for what I'm doing with regular *df.to_pickle()*

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand this paragraph and possibly my solution is the same:

> As of right now it seems my best solution is using the spacy method of serializing the list of docs (https://spacy.io/usage/saving-loading) and loading with pandas dataframe later.

But if not, you can modify type of doc to save your dataframe to parquet (https://spacy.io/api/doc#to_bytes)

```
df['corpus_spacy_doc'] = df['corpus_spacy_doc'].apply(lambda x: x.to_bytes())
df.to_parquet(path, engine="pyarrow")
```